# Can I write my own mySQL functions to use in mySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, function

Can I write a custom function that I can call when making mySQL queries eg.

My database table has fields 'filetype' and 'filename'. I want to perform a function on filename before returning the result.

```
$query = "SELECT filetype, MY_FUNCTION(filename) FROM table..";
$result = mysql_query($query);
return $result
```

SO $result now has the new values created by MY_FUNCTION. The original database data will be unchanged.

OK - so it looks like User Defined Functions are the way to go... how do I write my own user defined function? Can I use PHP to write it? Where do I save the function or do I include it in my globals file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION (FILENAME VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
BEGIN
       RETURN SUBSTR(filename, 1, 20);
END
$$


DELIMITER ;
```

To create the function, you just paste its code (sililar to provided above) in your favorite query tool, like `mysql.exe`, `MySQL Query Browser`, `phpmysqladmin` etc.

You can write `UDF`'s both in `C` and in `SQL`. In the latter case, you don't need to have a compiler.

The function I provided as an example is an `SQL UDF`. It just returns first `20` characters of the filename.

You can use any `MySQL` functions in an `SQL UDF`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, where do I write this code... do I need to compile a C program for running a UDF from a windows 2003 server? Do you know of a good tutorial for this or can you please guide me through the process. Many thanks

Comment: Custom functions are written in the MySQL database, just as tables are.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is called [User Defined Functions (UDF)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html).

And here is a [good repository](http://www.mysqludf.org/) of already pre-build functions, so you can check if something fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a stored procedure? http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedprocedures.html

Comment: I don't think he wants to change the data in the database, just apply the change to the results (outside the database).

Comment: Hi - correct, I dont want the data in the database to change. thanks

Comment: and you can't call stored procedure in select part of query.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, you can add used defined functions.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a user defined function in PHP (or at least not without writing a wrapper that will call your script), as UDFs are loaded as native code.